# how to get response from post

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have route as below

```
namespace :books
  resources :pages, only: [] do
    post 'lesson'
  end
end
```

controller.rb

```
def lesson
  begin
    @result = @user.lesson_details(Integer(params[:lesson_id]),
                              params[:lesson_name]
    head :ok
  rescue ArgumentError => e
    render_error(:bad_request, e.message)
  end
end
```

I am using postman for testing. Is there any way i can return `@result` on postman or in json?

Comment: can you try `return render(:json => @result)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The method `render` render displays results. Since you are trying to return a `json` object, you would want to put the `:json` as the key into the `render` as below.

```
def lesson
  begin
    @result = @user.lesson_details(Integer(params[:lesson_id]),
                              params[:lesson_name]
    return render(:json => @result)        
    head :ok
  rescue ArgumentError => e
    render_error(:bad_request, e.message)
  end
end
```

The reason we're doing a `return` is because, `rails` would throw an error if there is multiple`render` methods called.

Comment: The `begin` statement isn't needed.

Comment: getting error "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return"."

Comment: can you try putting the `render` statement above the `head :ok`?

Comment: thanks it worked but rubocop complains "Use the new Ruby 1.9 hash syntax"